# How can I replace a missing IKEA drawer slide?

Tags: drawers

I am missing one part of the drawer runner on one of my pieces of ikea furniture. It's the leftmost one in this picture, the part of the runner that attaches to the drawer itself:

[image]

Are drawer runners standardized to a degree that I can find a matching replacement part that wasn't specifically made for this piece of IKEA furniture? Or should I remove both parts of the runner from that one side of the drawer and replace with a new runner?

Comment: Did you lose the piece or was it not included?

Comment: Normally I'd flag this for closure as too localized - but IKEA is global - and they certainly are DIY oriented... ;)

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo -- The question applies to more than just my individual piece of Ikea furniture. It asks broader questions about drawer slides in general ("Are drawer runners standardized...", can a drawer have two different but comparable slides).

Comment: Is this a repair? If the piece was missing then the correct action is to go back to IKEA for a replacement.

Comment: Look for the manufacturer name stamped on the drawer slide. Blum, Knape & Vogt, Leksvik, Richelieu, Vess, etc. There has to be a name or trademark there along with a number, once you have that, you can pretty quickly find the rails you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would purchase a complete drawer slide from IKEA.

They're not expensive and then there won't be any questions as to whether they have changed the mechanics of the device or not.

Comment: If the slides are not sold individually, ask at the replacement part counter, next to the returns counter. There may be a small charge, or they may give it to you for free.

Comment: So are these parts on drawers not standardized? I really do have to go through Ikea? And would the downsides be to replacing it with a different slide that I get from Home Depot?

Comment: @maxedison I can't say what IKEA does or doesn't do. But I assure you that they will be able to sell you a replacement slide. They're not expensive... and if you get it from them you can be certain it will work. They are very easy to replace.

Comment: And for smaller bits (pegs, cams, screws, allen wrenches, etc.), they generally have a bunch of bins near the customer service / replacement parts counter so that you can help yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can ring IKEA, specify the piece(s) you need and they will send you out the replacement part so you don't even need to go back to the store.

When it happened to me they had forgot to include pieces so they sent it out free of charge. I'm not sure if they'll charge you if you lost it of your own accord.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that Ikea does not sell replacements for this part.  Nor could I order the part from them. 
I have tried replacing it with other slides and the other one broke too.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one seemed to answer the question about standardization - in general, yes but the Ikea slide I have are not standard with what I can find at Lowe's.

Answer (score 0):

I have what appear to be the same drawer slides on our IKEA dresser (they look the same as the picture, are 17.75" long). I found replacements slides on Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Prime-Line-Products-7211-Drawer-Self-Closing/dp/B00E8AF0LM?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=od_aui_detailpages00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E8AF0LM)